# Referenced control under dll is drawn in XAML but not building

Tags: .net, wpf, xaml, visual-studio-2012, dll

In a WPF project, I am trying to use a `Control` defined in a .dll.

1. I added the .dll as a reference to my project
2. I imported the required namespace in the XAML
3. I insert the control in XAML

The control is drawn correctly at design time with Visual Studio.
When I try to build the project however, I will get the below error:

```
Type 'xxx' is not defined
```

My project and the .dll both are targeting .NET Framework 4.5.

**How is it possible that the control is drawn correctly at design-time but it fails to build it?**

EDITED:

Namespace import into XAML:

```
xmlns:myControls="clr-namespace:MyControl.Controls;assembly=MyControl"
xmlns:myControl="clr-namespace:MyControl;assembly=MyControl"
```

Actual control (that fails to build)

```
<myControls:MyControl/>
```

And the referenced dll properties:

[image]

When building, Visual Studio gives error:

```
Type 'MyControl.Controls.MyControl' is not defined.
```

where the error points to MainWindow.xaml and MainWindow.g.i.vb as well.

Comment: Does the .dll end up in the bin folder of the WPF project?  If not, ensure Copy Local = true

Comment: please add your code, with using statements...

Comment: Yes, Copy Local=True and the .dll ends up in the bin folder. If I comment out the control, the build succeeds.

Comment: I picked the reference from another project's Bin-folder (not recommended I believe). When I copy the dll into my project's root folder, the build succeeds. I don't still understand that at design time the dll is found but not at compile time anymore.